# In Dart, check if a class inherits parent class with type checking

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, bloc

I am try to find a safe way to use Bloc patterns in Flutter with a very strong type checking.

Let's say we have this simple Bloc code:

```dart
// States 

abstract class CourseState {}

class CourseInitialized extends CourseState {}

// Events 

abstract class CourseEvent {}

class CourseFetch extends CourseEvent {}

class CourseLoaded extends CourseEvent {}

// Bloc (somewhere in the Bloc)

final event = CourseFetch();
```

In dart we can use the **is** operator to check if the **event** variable is of type **CourseFetch** or **CourseEvent**:

```dart
event is CourseFetch // true
event is CourseEvent // true
```

But nothing forbid me to check if event is of type CourseState or even of type a num, String, etc.

```dart
event is CourseInitialized // false
event is String // false
```

Of course is this case event can't be a String, because it has been initialized with CourseFetch() class.

I am try to find a way to forbid programmers (us) to wrongly write if statement that can never be evaluate to true.

In my case scenario I would like to have a way that stop me to check if a variable *event* of a certain type *state* in the IDE and give me a red squiggly line.

```dart
if (event is CourseInitialized) { 
// the above line should give me a warning, this variable event is not a State
}
```

Any ideas? Linting tools or syntax that can help?

**UPDATE**:
I follow Rémi suggestion and try out Freezed, it makes the code simple and add up a safe type checking. [Here](https://github.com/thomasgazzoni/flutter_freezed_bloc_built_value) you can find a complete implementation of Bloc with Freezed and Built Value.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing (nor is it possible to know that you checked all the possible cases).

What you can instead do is replace the `is` operator with a function that does it for you.

One example of this is what the code-generator [Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed) does.

Instead of:

```dart
abstract class CourseEvent {}

class CourseFetch extends CourseEvent {}

class CourseLoaded extends CourseEvent {}
```

You would write:

```dart
@freezed
abstract class CourseEvent with _$CourseEvent {
  factory CourseEvent.fetch() = _Fetch;
  factory CourseEvent.loaded() = _Loaded;
}
```

Which is then used as:

```dart
CourseEvent event;

event.when(
  fetch: () => print('Fetch event'),
  loaded: () => print('Loaded event'),
);
```

Comment: Hi @rémi-rousselet, thanks to point it out Freezed library, it works very well. I made [this simple project](https://github.com/thomasgazzoni/flutter_freezed_bloc_built_value) definitely it simply a lot the Bloc code.