Checking if one Type variable inherits from another Type variable
TLDR: If I have two Type variables, how do I check if one inherits from another? What I want is something like this:
Type typeString = String;
Type typeInt = int;
Type typeNum = num;

inheritsFrom(typeString, typeInt) // false
inheritsFrom(typeInt, typeNum) // true

I can't use the mirror package as it is not supported by Flutter.
In my flutter app I have a view, in which a display a grid of data. In this view I have this whole column configuration, where each column has a configuration object associated with it, which tells me a few things, but in this case the most important thing is that it has a generic type, which tells me the type of the values in this column.
Here is some of the code for the column configuration class:
class ColumnConfiguration<T> {
  final String columnName;
  final bool isEditable;
  final bool isDisplayed;
  final bool isSearchable;
  final int columnIndex;
  final List<TextInputFormatter> inputFormatters;
  Type get type => T;


  ColumnConfiguration({
    required this.columnName,
    required this.isEditable,
    required this.isDisplayed,
    required this.isSearchable,
    required this.columnIndex,
    required this.inputFormatters,
  });

  ColumnValue<T> createColumnValue(T? value) {
    return ColumnValue<T>(value, this);
  }
}

I also have a functionality in this view, where I export the grid to Excel. I do some checks to see which columns should be exported, one of which is if the type is supported by my excel exporter class. Currently my excel exporter has a map, which has a type as its key, and a function to map a value of that type to an excel cell value. Here is the map:
static Map<Type, CellValue Function(dynamic)> cellValueConverterMap = {
    String: (value) => TextCellValue(value ?? ''),
    int: (value) => IntCellValue(value ?? 0),
    double: (value) => DoubleCellValue(value ?? 0),
    bool: (value) => TextCellValue((value ?? false) ? 'Ja' : 'Nej'),
    DateTime: (value) => TextCellValue(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss').format(value ?? DateTime.now())),
    // I would prefer to only have displayable object here, as EditDeliverySiteDto and Project both use the same
    // mapping and inherit from DisplayableObject. I have, however, not found a way to implement this. 
    // I simply can't figure out, how to check if one Type variable inherits from another Type variable.  
    DisplayableObject: (value) => TextCellValue(value?.displayText ?? ''),
    EditDeliverySiteDto: (value) => TextCellValue(value?.displayText ?? ''),
    Project: (value) => TextCellValue(value?.displayText ?? ''),
    Null: (value) => const TextCellValue(''),
  };

Then, when I invoke my ExportToExcel method I check if the type is supported like this:
ExcelExporter.exportToExcel(
      fileName: 'some_file_name.xlsx',
      sheetName: 'some_sheet_name',
      data: _someData,
      headers: listOfMyColumnConfigurations
          .where((cc) => cc.isDisplayed && ExcelExporter.cellValueConverterMap.containsKey(cc.type))
          .map((cc) => cc.columnName),
      startedCallBack: _showSnackBarGenerateExcelFileStarted,
      failedCallBack: _showSnackBarGenerateExcelFileError,
      completedCallBack: _showSnackBarGenerateExcelFileComplete,
    );

The issue with this, is that I can't check if cc.type is an inherited type of any of the keys in my map, I can only check if they are exactly identical. So when I have a column confiuration for a Project, which inherits from DisplayableObject, I don't want to have to add Project to the map of cell converters, I just want to use the DisplayableObject converter.
Is there a way to do this?

please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743618/in-dart-check-if-a-class-inherits-parent-class-with-type-checking?rq=2

@Normal1One that really does not solve my issue. I do not, have an instance to check against. If I did, I would indeed be able to use the is-operator, but in this case, the is-operator would just check that my Type variable is of type Type and always return true.

RuntimeType is only for debugging purposes and the application code shouldn't depend on it. It can be overridden by classes to return fake values and probably returns unusable values when transpiled to JS.
You should use classes and comparing classes to parent clases will work as you expected them to with the operator is.
class typeString{}
class typeInt extends typeNum{}
class typeNum{}

(typeString is typeInt) // false
(typeInt is typeNum) // true


I am not using RuntimeType, I am using type variables. This answer does not really help my issue.
